# Best way to access settings from parent class in child class

Tags: c#

I have a project where I'm implementing an API that has about 300 methods and I want to separate them out so they're organized by the API category.

I'm trying to lay out my classes so that I have a parent class that has settings, and organize child classes inside of the parent that have access to those settings. I found a horribly convoluted way to do this that probably breaks every rule on the planet. Is there a more standardized way of going about this than what I've come up with?

I want to be able to create an instance of the parent class like:

```
var foo = new Foo(new FooSettings("Hello"));
```

and be able to access the functions in the child classes like:

```
foo.Bar1.WriteTag();
foo.Settings.Tag = "Woot";
foo.Bar2.WriteTag();
```

with Bar1 and Bar2 having access to the settings I gave when I created the instance of Foo. My current class layout is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public FooSettings Settings;

    public FooMethods.Bar1 Bar1 { get; }
    public FooMethods.Bar2 Bar2 { get; }

    public Foo(FooSettings settings)
    {
        Settings = settings;
        Bar1 = new FooMethods.Bar1(ref Settings);
        Bar2 = new FooMethods.Bar2(ref Settings);
    }
}

public class FooSettings
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public FooSettings(string tag)
    {
        Tag = tag;
    }
}

public class FooMethods
{
    public class Bar1
    {
        private FooSettings Settings { get; }

        public Bar1(ref FooSettings settings)
        {
            Settings = settings;
        }

        public void WriteTag()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar1 " + Settings.Tag);
        }
    }

    public class Bar2
    {
        private FooSettings Settings { get; }

        public Bar2(ref FooSettings settings)
        {
            Settings = settings;
        }

        public void WriteTag()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar2 " + Settings.Tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty OK-ish to me. See also my answer. Is there anything in particular that worries you?

Comment: It just smells funny to me... like there's a better way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Can you lay out some ideas/requirements about how you would like it to look, even if you don't quite know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you following changes .

You can have a base class for FooMethods , something like FooMethodsBaseClass which will be parent class for Bar1 and Bar2 .

You can move all your common codes, methods to base class and Bar1 and Bar2 can access those .

This way you can segregate the code . And in future, if you get requirement in which you have to implement in both in Bar1 and Bar2 you can add it in single place, in base class.
Thus you can avoid duplicates .

As you can see WriteTag i made it as virtual . And overridden by child classes

Also passing as ref is not needed

Further more, you can have interface for FooMethodsBaseClass. This will actually help you in writing unit tests

Base Interface :

```
 public interface IFooMethodsBaseClass
    {
        void WriteTag();
    }
```

Base class:

```
    public class FooMethodsBaseClass:IFooMethodsBaseClass
    {
        protected IFooSettings Settings { get; }

        public FooMethodsBaseClass(IFooSettings settings)
        {
            Settings = settings;
        }

        public virtual void WriteTag()
        {

        }
    }
```

Bar1 class

```
public class Bar1: FooMethodsBaseClass
{
    public Bar1(IFooSettings fooSettings):base(fooSettings)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteTag()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar1 " + Settings.Tag);
    }
}
```

Bar2 Class

```
public class Bar2: FooMethodsBaseClass
{
    public Bar2(IFooSettings fooSettings):base(fooSettings)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteTag()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar2 " + Settings.Tag);
    }
}
```

Foo and Foo Settings . 
Foo settings can be derived from interface as well. Since you are creating Foo by passing FooSettings , by introducing interface based injection you can write unit tests without any dependency by mocking

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public IFooSettings Settings;

        public IFooMethodsBaseClass Bar1 { get; }
        public IFooMethodsBaseClass Bar2 { get; }

        public Foo(IFooSettings settings)
        {
            Settings = settings;
            Bar1 = new Bar1(Settings);
            Bar2 = new Bar2(Settings);
        }
    }

    public class FooSettings: IFooSettings
    {
        public string Tag { get; set; }

        public FooSettings(string tag)
        {
            Tag = tag;
        }

    }

    public interface IFooSettings
    {
        string Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally you can create Foo instance like this

```
 IFooSettings fs = new FooSettings("1");
 Foo foo = new Foo(fs);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the tremendous improvement here, but OK. One thing though - why bother with the interface for FooSettings? If it's just a "dumb" data object (and settings objects usually are), then there's no point in mocking it in unit tests. Just use `FooSettings` directly wherever you need them.

Comment: I agree. Now its "dumb" object . but i just opened an option in future , in case if we are going to add more functionalities to FooSettings . We can go ahead without interface if there is no more functionalities going to be added

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this actually seems pretty fine. A few tweaks I would make myself:

- There's not much need for child classes here - I would use namespaces instead. Makes it easier to write.
- There's no need for the `ref` qualifier in the `BarX` constructors.
- `BarX` classes could be lazily instantiated when someone first accesses `Foo.BarX`. When using such huge APIs, the typical use case will probably just use a few methods, so most `BarX`s will never be needed.
- Make `Foo.Settings` readonly, either through a property or just with a `readonly` qualifier.
- Optionally, pass the `Foo` instance to the `BarX` instead of the settings. `BarX` can access the settings (and more if needed) through that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on lazy instantiating Foo.BarX? Maybe an example?

Comment: @EmilySamanthaHeiner - Without pretty formatting - `private Bar1 bar1; public Bar1 Bar1 { get { if (this.bar1 == null) { this.bar1 = new Bar1(this.Settings); } return this.bar1; }}`

Comment: Ok, maybe come up with some prettier names. Having a type `Bar1`, a property `Bar1` and a field `bar1` is just begging for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

May be to make the settings a static field?

```
        public class Foo
        {
            public static FooSettings Settings;

            public FooMethods.Bar1 Bar1 { get; private set; }
            public FooMethods.Bar2 Bar2 { get; private set; }

            public Foo(FooSettings settings)
            {
                Settings = settings;
                Bar1 = new FooMethods.Bar1();
                Bar2 = new FooMethods.Bar2();
            }
        }

        public class FooSettings
        {
            public string Tag { get; set; }

            public FooSettings(string tag)
            {
                Tag = tag;
            }
        }

        public class FooMethods
        {
            public class Bar1
            {
                public void WriteTag()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bar1 " + Foo.Settings.Tag);
                }
            }

            public class Bar2
            {
                public void WriteTag()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bar2 " + Foo.Settings.Tag);
                }
            }
        }
```

And methods bar1 and bar2 can be implemented by the one class. Or its just for example?

Comment: It's obviously just an example. Also, what does it help to make the settings private? Especially if you're assigning them in a *constructor*? That seems just confusing.

Comment: I need to be able to have multiple instances of Foo, so a static field won't work for me.

Comment: Vilx, private - nohow, adding {get; private set;} will solve your cognitive dissonance with constructor assigning, i guess
Emily, got it. Remove ref`s, because  "settings" are actually a reference to a class object